# LINQ query to delete particular record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I need to delete a record from the table

For one CategoryId I will have several serviceTypes..

Ex: CategoryId = 123 Service types related to this is 1 2 3 4 5

I need a query to delete servicetype 3 to CategoryId 123..

My method will be I will pass

```
Deleterecord(CategoryId,ServiceTypeId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using LINQ to SQL:

```
var service = Services
    .Include("Category")
    .First(s => s.ServiceId == 3 && s.Category.CategoryId == 123);
context.Services.DeleteOnSubmit(service);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

If you're using Entity Framework:

```
var service = Services
    .Include("Category")
    .First(s => s.ServiceId == 3 && s.Category.CategoryId == 123);
context.Services.DeleteObject(service);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression is an anonymous function and it is mostly used to create delegates in LINQ. Simply put, it's a method without a declaration, i.e., access modifier, return value declaration, and name.

Especially useful in places where a method is being used only once, and the method definition is short. It saves you the effort of declaring and writing a separate method to the containing class.

Benefits: 
    Reduced typing. No need to specify the name of the function, its return type, and its access modifier. 
    When reading the code you don't need to look elsewhere for the method's definition.

Lambda expressions should be short. A complex definition makes the calling code difficult to read.

for Example

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{11,37,52};
List<int> oddNumbers = numbers.where(n => n % 2 == 1).ToList();
```